# How to check that jcrop is initialized

Tags: jquery, jcrop

I would like to know how to check is my Jcrop initialized and then create `if` if is initialized. How to do this and is this possible ? I have jcrop from this page: [jcrop.org](http://jcrop.org/)

Here is my jcrop code. It is located in function `initJcrop` so maybe there is some way to check that this function is initialized?

```
var jcrop_api;

function initJcrop($width, $height)
{
  $('#jc_image').Jcrop({
      allowSelect: false,
      allowMove: true,
      aspectRatio: $width/$height,
  },function(){

    jcrop_api = this;
    jcrop_api.animateTo([0,0,$width, $height]);

  });

};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the fast way is to use an object, that containts the jcrop_api and other information about it.

In this way:

```
var jCrop={
initialized:false,
}
function initJcrop($width, $height)
{
  $('#jc_image').Jcrop({
      allowSelect: false,
      allowMove: true,
      aspectRatio: $width/$height,
  },function(){
    jCrop.initialized=true;
    jCrop.jcrop_api = this;
    jcrop_api.animateTo([0,0,$width, $height]);

  });

};
```

After that, you can check if jCrop is initialized

```
if (jCrop.initialized){
//code here 
}
```

Comment: But what if I use "destroy" jCrop ? jCrop.initialized will be still set on "true" right?

Comment: Yeah, of course. You have to set it to false after calling the destroy.

jCrop.jcrop_api.destroy()
jCrop.initialized=false;